# How to update tableView only if it scrolls slowly?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to call `tableView.reloadData()` only, if the tableView is scrolled slowly to avoid flickering.
To achieve this I monitor the scrolling speed in the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate Function.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let scrollSpeed:CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y - previousScrollViewYOffset
    previousScrollViewYOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if scrollSpeed < 1.0
    { 
        tViewMoves = false
        // tableView.reloadData()    
    }
    else
    {
        tViewMoves = true   
    }
}
```

The Problem is that the Bool tViewMoves is accessed and set very often but dont changes its value from true to false and vice versa. Nevertheless `tableView.reloadData()` is called every time the Bool is accessed and causes some flickering while the tableView is scrolled. I tried to overcome this issue by adding an observer with `.New` option to tViewMoves. But the `tableView.reloadData()` method is still called every time tViewMoves is set even if it doesn't changes its value.

```
self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "tViewMoves", options: .New, context: &observerContext)

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
if context == &observerContext {
     if let newValue = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] {
           print("changed: \(newValue)") 
           tableView.reloadData()   
        }
    } 
else {
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)

    }
}

deinit {
    self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "tViewMoves", context: &observerContext)
}
```

Any suggestions how I could overcome this issue?

UPDATE EDIT:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:CalendarCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CalendarCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    let buttonView = self.buttonViewArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.aBackgroundView.addSubview(buttonView)

    if tViewMoves == false
    {

        let buttonStarView = self.buttonStarViewArray[indexPath.row]
        buttonStarView.myDelegate = cell
        buttonStarView.kalenderVCDelegate = self
        cell.aBackgroundView.addSubview(buttonStarView)


        //add tapRecognizer
        let tap = SubclassedTapRec(target: self, action: #selector(KalenderVC.tapButtonView(_:)))
        tap.myTag = buttonStarView.tag
        buttonStarView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


    }
    return cell
}
```

UPDATE EDIT 2:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    let myCell = cell as! CalendarCell

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        let buttonStarView = self.buttonStarViewArray[indexPath.row]
        buttonStarView.myDelegate = myCell
        buttonStarView.kalenderVCDelegate = self
        myCell.aBackgroundView.addSubview(buttonStarView)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not good experience for the user. Have you considered updateSection/insertRows/deleteRows methods that works without pausing scrolling animation?

Comment: @Thoms what do you have in you cell to make it flick? That should not happen. Can you Share your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: @rob180 i created a custom calendar, that has to do some search operation in a database and then draws the content in the cell. When the tableview moves fast, I just draw a plain calendar month without contents which works fine but as soon as the movement stops/becomes slower the tableView shall show the dataBase contents which takes some time for calculation. I will just updated the question with the cellForRowATIndexPath method

Comment: @Thoms you should do the Database operations ASYNC, that way the app wont flick

Comment: @Thoms `myCell.aBackgroundView.addSubview(buttonStarView)` this must be done inside `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`

Comment: Why do you reload all the table view when a cell is drawn?

Comment: Just to end this up: My main mistake was making the calculations in a drawRect: method. So every time a new cell appeared the calculation of the coordinates to be drawn was started. Putting the calculation of the coordinates to be drawn in an external class made it possible to make operations ASYNC work -> calculate the coordinates in the background first and then draw the view in the main queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend something like this:

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    // Get data from db
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // update the cell (Make all UI operations here)
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Looking at your code i would change this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

        let testView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
        testView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 10)
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            cell.addSubview(testView)
            //You should not reload the complete table view from inside the draw methods because it will cause a infinite loop
            //tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }



    return cell
}
```

Comment: I tried to do the database stuff in operation ASYNC as you suggested and put it in the willDisplayCell method. Now I get an exception: 'This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes'.

Comment: make sure all UI operations are in the Main Queue

Comment: that gives me the same exception message. I just wrote a simple example app. Can you tell me where the mistake in cellForRowAtIndexPath is?

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

        let testView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
        testView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 10)
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        cell.addSubview(testView)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }



    return cell
}
```